# PHP updating database

Tags: php, sql, database, post

I'm having problems with the following code to update a database. There are no errors, and I know it's not the database because I have another 'GET' script which uses the same &con information and returns data from the database just fine. However, the database just never updates.

```
 <?php
    define("DB_DSN","xxx");
    define("DB_HOST","xxx");
    define("DB_USER","xxx");
    define("DB_PASS","xxx");

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_DSN) or die('Could not select database');    
    $id = base64_decode($_POST["id"]);
    $deaths = base64_decode($_POST["deaths"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths =' . $id .' WHERE DeathID= ' . $deaths . '" ;     
    $uresult = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    if(! $uresult )
    {
      die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($con);
    exit;
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: Are you sure your `$_POST` variables have in tem what you expect? Are you sure they're Base64 encoded?

Comment: change your `UPDATE` statement to `"UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths ='" . $id . "' WHERE DeathID= '" . $deaths . "'";`

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
"UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths =' . $id .' WHERE DeathID= ' . $deaths . '" ;
```

should be

```
"UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths ='" . $deaths . "' WHERE DeathID= " . $id . " ;
```

I think.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly insert this code without using variables:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `Level1` SET `Deaths`= '".$deaths."' WHERE DeathID= ".$id.");
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths =' . $id .' WHERE DeathID= ' . $deaths . '" ;
```

Should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths ='" . $deaths . "' WHERE DeathID= '" . $id . "'";
```

Comment: Considering he's using double quotes and trying to concatenate using single quotes, I'd say it does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do `echo  $sql ;` and then you will know your error :)

Points are here interpreted as caracter not as concatenation operator,so update will update every Death that has `id ='.value.'` ,it not exists in database and then nothing happens.

**Replace this :**

```
$sql = "UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths =' . $id .' WHERE DeathID= ' . $deaths . '" ;
```

By this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths ='$id' WHERE DeathID= '$deaths'" ;
```

Comment: @user2775839 please validate this answer so that it can be seen in the top and helps others

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo your variables at first and you don't neeed '.$id.' (actually it should be '".$id."') you can write Deaths = '$id' or Deaths = '$deaths' should be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please remove the dots from query as shown below it will solve problem.

$sql = "UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths ='$id' WHERE DeathID= '$deaths'" ;